# php function as function parameter

Tags: php, xml, parsing, function

Consider the following function declaration for checking current language on a bilingual website:

```
function checkNewsLanguage(){
    $requiredURL = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $myLanguage = explode('?lang=',$requiredURL);
    if($myLanguage=='en')
        return false;
    else return true;
}
```

Then I get some XML objects in the required language using functions like:

```
function item1('checkNewsLanguage')
    if(checkNewsLanguage()){
        $urlD = "someurl1";
        $xmlD = simplexml_load_file(cacheFetch($urlD,'cachedfeed1.xml',3600));
        $itemD = '';
        if($xmlD === FALSE)
            {$itemD = '';}
        else
            {$itemD = $xmlD->channel->item;}
    }
    else {
        $urlD = "someurl2";
        $xmlD = simplexml_load_file(cacheFetch($urlD,'cachedfeed2.xml',3600));
        $itemD = '';
        if($xmlD === FALSE)
            {$itemD = '';}
        else
            {$itemD = $xmlD->channel->item;}
    }
    return $itemD;
    }
function item2('checkNewsLanguage')
//Analogic procedure
```

I get `"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING, expecting '&' or T_VARIABLE "`. As you see the function calls in item1() and item2() are not correct. Any code help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function arguments need to be a variable, not just a string (as the error suggests). Your functions should be defined like:

`function item1($variableHere)` and not `function item2('string here')`.

As I look at your code again, it seems what you are trying to do is call a certain function based on the parameter of `item1()` and `item2()` (so if you pass `item1(foo)` you want to call the `foo()` function.

Try:

```
function item1($function)
{
    if ($function()) 
    { 
        ...
    }
}
```

and similar for `item2()`. This way you can call `item1('checkNewsLanguage')` and that is the function it will call inside of the body.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is on line:

```
function item1('checkNewsLanguage')
```

You can't have `'checkNewsLanguage'` in the paranthesis there. You need to have a variable that accepts the function argument.